# 14 volts on bare copper ground wire at light switch with breaker off & low volts on hot wire with breaker on

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, grounding, multiway-switch

so I have two light switches on each end of our hallway that controls the hall lights (3 way switches). For years it hasn't worked or one of the switches were bad, because you could wiggle it, and the light would turn on. Today,  I decided to change the switches. I cut the breaker off and then confirmed power was off using my voltage pen. Well, when I touched the bare copper wire, it would beep/turn red. I got my multimeter and tested it. Just by squeezing the clamps  on the end of my multimeter on the bare wire, it would show around 12-14V  at the one light switch,  and the other switch, on the bare wire, it will show around 8-10. I took both switches off, and turned power back on. On one light switch from ground to neutral, it will show 81v, from ground to hot (black wire) will show 0 volt and neutral (white) to traveler(white) it shows 80 volt. The outlets and other lights/switches have the correct voltage, so I'm confused on what could be causing this. ESPECIALLY the 14volts on the bare ground wire with the breaker off. I know if it runs close enough to a hot wire,  it can show some voltage, but 14v??? I'm surprised this hasn't caused a fire, but thank the Lord it hasn't. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I'm pretty handy and feel I can tackle this my myself with a little help.

Comment: Low voltage showing on circuits with the breaker off is usually phantom voltage.  It can be a lot higher than 14v sometimes going up to 80 or 90v.  One test is to connect a light, if the light lights, you have a problem.  You might have lost a neutral connection on that circuit.  Hot to neutral should ~120v, hot to ground ~120v, neutral to ground 0v.  This is for for real neutral and not whites used for travellers/hots.

Comment: Measure the amps on with the breaker OFF, see if you're still worried. Volts don't start fires, watts do (ok, technically Joules, but nobody uses that).